# How to properly pass typescript interface from React parent to child to grandchild

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to Typescript and learning to incorporate it into React. What I'm struggling with is what is the proper way to pass a prop two levels down to a grandchild along with the prop type? Do you build an identical interface in each component? Do you export the interface in the parent component and import it in both the child and the grandchild? Or do you only define the interface in the parent and not type check it in child and grandchild? I ask the question because I'm trying to pass 5 props from a parent component to a grandchild and feel I'm either having to write/import numerous interfaces in the child component just to pass it to my grandchild only to have to do so again to use it in the grandchild. Apologies if I'm not clear with my question.

For example, in this situation how do we pass the "somePropType" interface down to the grandchild?

```
export function ParentComponent(){
interface somePropType {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}

const someProp: somePropType = {
    firstname: 'foo',
    lastname: 'bar'
}

return (
    <ChildComponent someProp={someProp}/>
)
}

export function ChildComponent({ someProp }){
    return (
        <GrandchildComponent someProp={someProp}/>
    )
}

export function GrandchildComponent({ someProp }){
    return (
        <div>{`${someProp.firstname} ${someProp.lastname}`}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I do is this:

```
interface somePropType {
    firstname: string;
    lastname: string;
}
export function ParentComponent(){
    const someProp: somePropType = {
        firstname: 'foo',
        lastname: 'bar'
    }

    return (
        <ChildComponent someProp={someProp}/>
    )
}

interface ChildProps {
    someProp: somePropType
}
export function ChildComponent(props: ChildProps){
    const { someProp } = props
    return (
        <GrandchildComponent someProp={someProp}/>
    )
}

interface GrandchildProps {
    someProp: somePropType
}
export function GrandchildComponent(props: GrandchildProps){
    const { someProp } = props
    return (
        <div>{`${someProp.firstname} ${someProp.lastname}`}</div>
    )
}
```

Basically pass down the prop type on every child. This way, VSCode will also give you autocomplete with the children components
For every component, it is best to have an interface for the props in the component

Comment: So in the case that you're doing this and each component is in its own file, you would be exporting the interface from the parent component and importing it in every child/grandchild component that uses it?

Comment: Nope. Just export the `somePropType` for the other components to use. Also make a new `props` interface for every component

Comment: what happens if you don't make new `prop` for each component, but just use `somePropType` in all children?